# WordPress database error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Below `WordPress` database error is coming:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_author_followers WHERE
>   author_id =  made by require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),

Here is my code.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}author_followers WHERE author_id = $author_id", OBJECT );
$followcounter = count($results);
return $followcounter;
```

Comment: try to echo your query .

Comment: The braces are there to tell PHP that $wpdb->prefix is one expression, they are not the issue. My guess is that $author_id is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was correct, Just Author ID was not there, I have fixed this issue. Thanks for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

echo "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}author_followers WHERE author_id = $author_id";

Try to echo $author_id before the SQL query, and check SQL statement after replacing $author_id with its value.

Thanks